# optimizing MLP with GWO to replace gradient descent using mealpy resulting same accuracy of 0.5 for all the epochs

Tags: keras, optimization, neural-network, mlp

[result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEysY.jpg)

```
`import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from mealpy.swarm_based import GWO
#from mealpy.evolutionary_based import FPA    
class HybridMlp:

    def __init__(self, dataset, n_hidden_nodes, epoch, pop_size):
        self.X_train, self.y_train, self.X_test, self.y_test = dataset[0], dataset[1], dataset[2], dataset[3]
        self.n_hidden_nodes = n_hidden_nodes
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.pop_size = pop_size

        self.n_inputs = self.X_train.shape[1]
        self.model, self.problem_size, self.n_dims, self.problem = None, None, None, None
        self.optimizer, self.solution, self.best_fit = None, None, None

    def create_network(self):
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(self.n_hidden_nodes[0], input_dim=self.n_inputs, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dense(self.n_hidden_nodes[1], input_dim=self.n_hidden_nodes[0], activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dense(self.n_hidden_nodes[2], input_dim=self.n_hidden_nodes[1], activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        self.model = model
        self.problem_size = self.n_dims = np.sum([np.size(w) for w in self.model.get_weights()])

    def create_problem(self):
        self.problem = {
            "fit_func": self.fitness_function,
            "lb": [-1, ] * self.n_dims,
            "ub": [1, ] * self.n_dims,
            "minmax": "max",
            #"log_to": None,
            "save_population": False,
            "n_dims": 35,
        }

    def decode_solution(self, solution):
       wh12, wh22, wh13, wh23, bo1, bo2, bo3 ]
        weight_sizes = [(w.shape, np.size(w)) for w in self.model.get_weights()]
        weights = []
        cut_point = 0
        for ws in weight_sizes:
            temp = np.reshape(solution[cut_point: cut_point + ws[1]], ws[0])
           
            weights.append(temp)
            cut_point += ws[1]
        self.model.set_weights(weights)

    def prediction(self, solution, x_data):
        self.decode_solution(solution)
        return self.model.predict(x_data)

    def training(self):
        self.create_network()
        self.create_problem()
        
        
        self.optimizer = GWO.RW_GWO(self.problem, self.epoch, self.pop_size)
        # self.optimizer = FPA.BaseFPA(self.problem, self.epoch, self.pop_size)
        #self.optimizer = SMA.BaseSMA(self.problem, self.epoch, self.pop_size)
        #self.optimizer = GA.BaseGA(self.problem, self.epoch, self.pop_size)
        #self.optimizer = VCS.BaseVCS(self.problem, self.epoch, self.pop_size)
        
        #---mytest
        
        self.solution, self.best_fit = self.optimizer.solve()
        print(self.solution,self.best_fit)

    def fitness_function(self, solution):  # Used in training process
        self.decode_solution(solution)
        yhat = self.model.predict(self.X_train)
        yhat = np.argmax(yhat, axis=-1).astype('int')
        acc = accuracy_score(self.y_train, yhat)
        return acc`
```

my project is a binary classification for malicious link detection using a dataset of 35 features.
my MLP model got an accuracy of 94.5 using the built-in Adam optimizer in keras.
now I am trying to optimize the model with a grey wolf optimizer to replace adam optimizer in mealpy.
When I run the code, I get an accuracy of 0.5, repeatedly, no matter how I change the number of epochs, pop_size, number of hidden layers, and number of neurons.
I am putting the code with this question.
note: i tried some other different optimizers such as FPA, still same.
appreciate any advice.
thank you very much.

Comment: argmax is incorrect for binary classification, class predictions are made by thresholding against 0.5

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I did that and it actually started to update..
Thanks again and appreciated